# apt update error ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates

**I faced this error when executing update command this happend after reinstalling the eset endponit anitvirus . now what should I do?**

```
hm@hm-Aspire-V3-571G:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                            
Hit:3 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                          
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                          
Hit:5 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                     
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
hm@hm-Aspire-V3-571G:~$
```

Comment: I don't see any error.

Comment: There is no error - what output did you expect?